# What methodology should I choose? If hiearchical, what model design?

Tags: bayes, hierarchical-bayesian, gibbs, metropolis-hastings, multilevel-analysis

I am working on a problem that has can beyond my level of understanding. I am quite familiar with R, so that would be my preferred choice but I also have access to SAS.

**Data**

I have created a fake dataset with a couple of rows [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mAyKRV24mwYJugU_8OmOdRCXz8FoomvH5JKkhhJNcGk/edit?usp=sharing)

My dataset is at the level of insurance "plans". Each plan belongs under a "contract". Each plan has what is known as a "formulary", which details the drugs that the insurance plan covers. Patients belonging to a plan can submit an appeal if they wish for their insurance to cover a drug that is not covered under the formulary. What I am trying to model is the number of appeals requests a plan receives during the year given information about the plan and their formulary.

So, for 3097 different plans, I have the following information:

- # of appeals requests received
- contract ID
- formulary ID
- enrollment (~ number of patients enrolled in the plan for the year)

There are 584 different contracts. Some contracts have multiple plans under them, some only have one plan.

There are 297 unique formularies. Again, some formularies belong to only one plan, some formularies are shared by multiple plans. Each unique formulary has two main metrics of interest:

- # of drugs covered
- % of drugs covered that require prior authorization

**Model**

I immediately thought of using Poisson regression, since the response variable is the number of events occurring during a fixed time interval. There also seems to be over-dispersion so I have looked into negative binomial regression instead. Also, since the units are of differing size (enrollment) I am using the offset option.

The problem arises with the fact that the request rates of plans that share formularies or contracts are probably related to each other and I don't exactly know how to capture this relationship. There also may be issues with grouping using contract and/or formulary due to the fact that quite a few contracts and formularies belong to only a single plan. I initially tried designing a hierarchical model (I have limited experience with Gibbs sampling) but I can't seem to design a model that works. I have almost no experience with mixed-effects models and no matter how many times I read about them I can't see how exactly I would set it up for my problem.

I am mostly interested in the effect that **# of drugs covered** and **% of drugs covered that require prior authorization** have on rate of requests for a plan, but I understand  that many plans will share covariates and the errors of plans within the same contract may be correlated.